# Aggregate datetime

Tags: python, datetime

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime
import itertools
import os
import csv
from fredapi import Fred
```

So I connect with the Fed API and do the following (data_i is just storing the data from the FED and creating a dataframe.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data={"CUSR0000SEFV": data3, "CUUR0000SEFV": data4, "CPIAUCSL": data5,"CPIAUCNS":data6,"UNRATE": data7,"UNRATENSA":data8})
macro3 = df1
macro3.reset_index(inplace=True)
macro3.rename(columns={'index': 'date'}, inplace=True)
```

I get the following

```
    date     col1     col2     ...

2011-01-01 220.223   221.187
2011-02-01 221.309   221.898
```

I need help to transform it to this

```
    date    col1      col2 ...
2011-01-02 220.223   221.187
2011-01-09 220.223   221.187
2011-01-16 220.223   221.187
```

I tried doing this but I just don't know how to aggregate and print duplicates

```
macro3.date = (macro3.date + datetime.timedelta(days=7))
```

Comment: what exactly is the transformation doing?

Comment: @Simon I need it to create more dates and fill the columns with duplicates. The data is updated 1 time a month so I just want to create more dates in between

Comment: you have posted some data  that can be used for a complete response. what are data1, data2, and so on in your example?

Answer (score 1):

you may use `resample()` and filling methods. for example, this one changes the frequency to a weekly one:

`pd.DataFrame.resample("W").ffill()`